# Google play services appinvite_styles.xml error

Tags: android, eclipse, styles, admob, google-play-services

I'm trying to figure out how to fix this issue -

I want to have my project targeted at `API 16 (Jellybean 4.1.2)`. I added the google play services and imported as a library project for my project. I set it to target the `API 23` (Latest). I'm still getting some errors. I tried adding `appcompat` but it seems it's not working. I'm doing in Eclipse. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you import your google-play-services-library into your eclipse workspace, do set its project build target as latest API 23, under Android tab of project properties. Goto eclipse menu project -> cleanup. Then once you import the google-play-services-library as a library under Android tab of your Project properties. Don't import it in your java build path. You will still see those appcompat errors, then again change your project's project build target to latest API 23 under Android tab of your project properties. Goto eclipse menu project -> cleanup. This should solve your errors.

Comment: Okay, when I set my project build target to latest API 23, am I able to run this app on my phone and it's at API 16?

Comment: Hmm, I just tested my phone and it worked. I recalled that targeting API 23 would cause an error... I think I got confused with android manifest and project properties....Thanks!!